# How to save all added/remove items, uploaded images, etc when I change the Vue Route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli-3

After adding/removing items from a list or uploading new file(like changing a profile image) those updates/files won't be there after I change the Vue Route and then go back to the Route where I did those changes. What should I do? Is there anything similar to `<keep-alive>` which is used with `<component>` tag?

Comment: The `router-view` API docs says that you can use `keep-alive`. Here is the doc reference: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view

Comment: Also consider using a store (Example: [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)) to keep reactive data across routes.